# mvc filter by dropdown selected text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

I have filters like below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "reqForm", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <p>
                <b>Filter by:</b><br />
                <b>Start Date</b> @Html.TextBox("searchByDateS",ViewBag.DateSFilter as string)
                <b>End Date</b> @Html.TextBox("searchByDateE",ViewBag.DateEFilter as string)
                <b>Leave Type</b> @Html.DropDownList("searchByLvType", "All Typies")
                <input type="submit" value="search" />
            </p>
        }
```

Controller is like below:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchByDateS, string searchByDateE, string searchByLvType, int? page)
        {
            if (searchByDateS != null)
                page = 1;
            else
                searchByDateS = currentFilter;
...
 ViewData["searchByLvType"] = new SelectList(lr.GetLvType(), "id", "LvType");
...
```

The parameter searchByLvType is selected.value of dropdown searchByLvType, How can I pass selected.text to the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use input type hidden

```
<input type="hidden" id="searchByLvTypeText" name="searchByLvTypeText"/>
```

when value change in dropdown  change value of hidden input

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="txt/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchByLvType").change(function()
     {
         $("#searchByLvTypeText").val($("#searchByLvType option:selected").text());
     });
});
</script>
```

then in your controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchByDateS, string searchByDateE, string searchByLvType, int? page,
string searchByLvTypeText)//drop down Text  
    {
}
```

Comment: Excellent job, simple and practical. Thanks a lot